# Programmatically Set Xcode Simulator, Keyboard and Touch ID Settings, For UI Tests

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xcode-ui-testing

My UI Tests fail with the iPhone simulator when its keyboard does not have the settings in the image below.  Is it possible to programmatically set these settings in the `setUp` method of a UI test, or somewhere before the test is run?  I would also like to do the same for the Touch ID enrollment settings.

I tried to see what code could be written by recording a UI test and then setting the keyboard, but unfortunately, simulator settings seem to be out of scope for the recording feature.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the following parameters in a script before running your tests.

```
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator ConnectHardwareKeyboard 0

Run the UI Tests

#optional - reset it
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator ConnectHardwareKeyboard 1
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Xcode 9.2 and iOS 11.2. I can't confirm whether it works on lower versions.

Comment: unfortunately not working for me either with xcode 10.1. Would have been nice :P

Comment: Note that the simulator needs to be shutdown when those settings are set and rebooted afterwards to have an effect.